# Electronic load for negative voltage PSU

Tags: mosfet, load, powermosfet, electronic-load, dummy-load

I am making a MOSFET based electronic load to test my PSU rails.
Below is a simplified version of my circuit with V2 as the PSU that is being tested. I want to be able to test negative voltage rails too, which must share a common ground with the supply voltage (V1).

**Is there some way to simply modify this type of design to allow for negative voltages to be loaded?**

thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYyZ1O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: NEW DESIGN]

Comment: Do you want one circuit to handle both positive and negative voltages, or do you want to design a circuit that will work for negative voltages (only)?

Comment: It would be great if it could handle both positive and negative voltages, but if that makes it much more complicated then Negative voltages only is fine.

Ideally though, the Negative voltage circuit would not be so different from the positive version. that way I could make a universal PCB where I just have to change a few components to make it a negative version.

Thanks!

Comment: Your (read: every) op amp will have a hard time dealing with inputs below its own negative supply rail (read: it won't work). So, among other changes, you'll have to either modify the amp's supply, or find a way to transform the sensed voltage to an appropriate value.

Comment: How much voltage drop across R1 is acceptable? I.e., what's the maximum current you want to measure at what minumum V2?

Comment: I can operate this from a +/-12V supply if that helps. I was planning on using a linear regulator to derive the 5V from 12V, because I thought that would help with stability.

The rails I want to measure are also +12V or -12V at up to 4.5A (if possible).

so I guess the maximum voltage across R1 is 0.45V.

I chose 0.1 Ohms because it seems like I would have to dissipate less heat in the resistor

Comment: Easiest is to replace V1 with a set of batteries so it's supply is floating.

Comment: Ah that is a cleaver idea! You mean 2 batteries for Bipolar, or unipolar is fine? ( I don’t need full cutoff in the MOSFET).

Is there a way to do it without batteries since I want to operate this for long periods of time? I am ok with creating a new version just for the negative rail.

Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Voltage is always relative. Measure your negative voltage supply with your multimeters leads swapped, you'll measure positive. With a floating supply you just wire up your e-load to DUT accordingly.

Comment: The floating supply is helpful, but I would really like to find common power solution. Would it work if the op-amp was powered with +/-5V (non floating)

Comment: If the polarity is fixed, i.e. only negative for the new circuit, and you can provide dual supply for the op amp, you may be able to just 'reverse' your current circuit, i.e. basically use a P-FET instead of the N-FET and swap +/- inputs on the op amp.

Comment: Great, thanks! I think I understand. I have uploaded a picture of the new schematic above. is that what you meant?